# In the context of a video game, should we say a player is "on a level" or "in a level"?

Tags: word-choice

Is it safe to assume that the correct word is "on", because someone is usually on a stage and not in a stage?

Comment: How about "at level x" or "at a certain level"? I think this is the common preposition used in connection with level.

Comment: I think _on, in,_ or _at_ would all work just fine. And I can't buy into your "on a stage" justification; _on stage_ is an idiomatic expression, and I don't think the parallel with a video game level is strong enough to consider it a model or precedent.

Comment: @painfulenglish "at level X" refers to your character's stats, not to what area of the game they are currently *in*.

Comment: We got some opinions and speculations.  Can someone tell us what a game actually says when you play it?  Or what the game instructions say when you read them?

Answer (score 3):

After running through many possibilities in my head, I believe that "**on**" can usually be assumed to be a safe choice.

For example,

> After 24 hours, I'm finally on level 255 of Pacman.

I believe you also use "on" in the other video game variations as well (*server, map, chapter*...) but I'm open to hearing other possibilities.

As pointed out by @painfulenglish, "**at**" seems to be a safe substitute as well.

Comment: Yes, just like the floor of a building. "My apartment is __on__ the fifth floor". 'in' would just not work there. 'at' would not either, but you _could_ say "The elevator is at the ninth...no, now it's at the 10th floor".

Comment: Yeah "on" might work for Pacman specifically, but really for jump'n'runs or shooters or RPGs or what have you it doesn't work at all. I've been playing video games for 30 years now. I watch Twitch and YouTube for a living. I'm on Xbox Live, I'm on PSN, and I'm on whatever hilarious thingie Nintendo thinks they are doing. So that's my appeal to authority, and here's my anecdotal evidence: it's always *in*. It's never *on*. Like, ever. And *at* is not even an option.

Comment: Hey @RegDwigнt, thanks for the comment. Would you be able to provide some examples so I can update my answer? Or posting your own works as well.

Comment: @RegDwigнt Please provide more than anecdotal evidence to back up your claims.

Comment: @Winter well at least I do have the anecdotal evidence. (*And* the appeal to authority! Don't forget the appeal to authority.) This answer doesn't even have any of that in the first place. It's just one person's opinion. And your comment, in turn, doesn't even offer *that*. Frankly I'm in the lead right now. It's anyone's move but mine.

Answer (score 1):

"On a level" or "in a level" express different ideas.

In a game "in a level" means, that while playing the game, you go from stage to stage, usually advancing to a higher degrees of difficulty as you go. Each stage of the game is considered a level and while you play it you are in that level.

"On a level" is more a ranking, maybe expression your experince, your number of wins or your mastery of some skill. Some role playing games (RPGs) have often over 100 levels, which have nothing to do with the challenges you are facing, but more with how long or often you play.
It can also be used in the sense of "in a level" and probably won't be misunderstood, but not the other way around.

"At a level" would be a neutral expression and can be used in either case.

Comment: Hence, if you are playing Super Mario Bros, you are in a level?

Comment: @CedricMartens Yes, that's exactly how I meant it. Especially this type of older games often have this structure.